# How to generate a monthly revenue breakdown using start end dates on Opportunity object?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, forecast

The Opportunity object has project start and end dates along with total revenue. Need a way so that user can see a month by month breakdown with revenue divided over each month.

For example if start date is 05/2018 and end date is 07/2018 with revenue of 90,000 USD then one should be able to see three columns one for May, June, and July and with 30,000 in each column as a breakdown for revenue. The user should have ability to enter an override for the revenue for each month.

Comment: You can consider opportunityRevenueSchedule that does same at opportunity product level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is standard powerful Salesforce feature to achieve this requirement but it works at opportunity product level- Product Revenue Schedules.

There are plenty of examples to use this. Here is help article of salesforce: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=products_schedules_def.htm&type=5

Also, there is very well explained article on this topic that might help you:

https://garysmithpartnership.com/track-revenue-over-time/

P.S.: (I can not add content of these help articles as these are very lengthy).